# Whats wrong with this Collections.sort(List<T> lst)

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable

```
String largeNumber(final List<Integer> a)
{
    List<Numbers> lstNum=convert(a);
    Collections.sort(lstNum);
    return null;
}
List<Numbers> convert(List<Integer> lst)
{
    List<Numbers> lstNum=new ArrayList<Numbers>(lst.size());
    for(int i:lst)
    {
        lstNum.add(new Numbers(i));
    }

    return lstNum;
}
```

I have error on line :

```
Collections.sort(lstNum);
```

> ```
>  the method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Numbers>)
> ```

I cannot get what is wrong Collections.sort() takes List as argument. Why am I getting this error?

this is the code for Numbers class

```
class Numbers implements Comparable<Integer>
{
    String first=null;
    Numbers(int a)
    {
        first=String.valueOf(a);
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Integer second) {
        String one=first.concat(String.valueOf(second));
        String two=String.valueOf(second).concat(first);
        if(Integer.parseInt(one)>=Integer.parseInt(two))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to sort Numbers, but a Numbers is not comparable to another Numbers. It's only comparable to an Integer (which makes no sense).

Comment: `Numbers implements Comparable<Integer>` doesn't make sense. How is `sort` supposed to sort `Numbers` if they cannot be compared to other `Numbers`?? Either change this to `Numbers implements Comparable<Numbers>` or use `lstNum.sort()` with a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: Thank you JB, got it. Its a duplicate question. I cannot find a way to mark it duplicate and close.